# jQuery - Simple Step form

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and am trying to build a simple 3 steps form with jQuery. I was able to hide the gray title but I can't make it to show the next step.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/2pr3xtxf/6/)**

JS:

```
$('.js-next-step').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

  // 1. Hide gray title
  $(this).parents().next().closest('.js-title-step').hide();

  // 2. Show next step div
  $(this).parents().next().closest('.js-step').show();

  // 3. Scroll to next step div
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, which is a bit of a rip-off of how bootstrap works.

```
$('.js-next-step').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var nextStep = $(this).attr('data-next-step');

  $(nextStep).show();

});
```

Essentially you have a data attribute on the element which points to the element you want to show.

```
  <a class="btn btn-primary js-next-step" href="#" role="button" data-next-step='.step-2'>Continue to Step 2</a>
```

In the on click logic you could also do something which hides the current step.

Comment: your solution was the one that worked better for me. This is what I end up with: https://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/2pr3xtxf/7/

Comment: No worries, if you want it to act a bit nicer use slideToggle();

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#to1").on('click',function() {
    $("#step1").show();
    $("#step2").hide();
  });

  $("#to2").on('click',function() {
    console.log('to2');
    $("#step1").hide();
    $("#step2").show();
  });
  
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px silver;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="step1">
  <h3>Step 1</h3>
  <input type="button" value="Next" id="to2"/>
</div>

<div id="step2" style="display:none">
  <h3>Step 2</h3>
  <input type="button" value="Previous" id="to1"/>
</div>
```

You can simply assign unique ids to each element, and access them by id, like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="step1">

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#step1').show();
```

One possible answer after the comment:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("input[value=Next]").on('click',function(evt) {
    var $div = $(this).closest('div[id!="step"]');
    var $next = $div.next('div[id!="step"]');
    console.log('next', $div, $next);
    if ($next.length) {
      $div.hide();
      $next.show();
    } else {
      console.log('There is no next!!');
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px silver;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="step1">
  <h3>Step 1</h3>
  <input type="button" value="Next"/>
</div>

<div id="step2" style="display:none">
  <h3>Step 2</h3>
  <input type="button" value="Next"/>
</div>

<div id="step3" style="display:none">
  <h3>Step 3</h3>
  <input type="button" value="Next"/>
</div>
```

Comment: That sounds a nice idea but I would have to create the same script 3 times only to change its respective id. How to avoid repetition?

Comment: You can use a convention to name the steps ids. Then you can extract the value from the element's id to determine which is the next and the previous ids. There are so many easy ways to do it that there would be a lot of possible answers.

Comment: I've added included a new snippet to my answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">


$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#step1").show();
  $("#step2").hide();
  $("#step3").hide();
});

$('.js-next-step1').click(function(e) 
{
 alert("dfg");
  $("#step1").hide();
  $("#step2").show();
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('.js-next-step2').click(function(e) 
{
 e.preventDefault();

  $("#step1").hide();
  $("#step2").hide();
  $("#step3").show();
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="container">



  <form>
<!-- begin Step 1 -->
<div id="step1">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 here">
      <h2 class="color-black">Step 1</h2>
      <hr>
    </div>
 </div><!-- row -->
 
<div class="js-step-1">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 here">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control js-show-panel-tip" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
 </div><!-- row -->
  
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 here">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control js-show-panel-tip" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
   </div>
 </div><!-- row -->
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-primary js-next-step1" href="#" role="button">Continue to Step 2</a>
    </div>
  </div><!-- row -->
  
</div>
</div>
<!-- end Step 1 -->


<!-- begin Step 2 -->
<div id="step2">
<div class="row js-title-step">
    <div class="col-md-6 here">
      <h2 class="color-gray">Step 2</h2>
      <hr>
    </div>
</div><!-- row -->

<div class="step-2 js-step">
 
 
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 here">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
      </div>
    </div>
 </div><!-- row -->
 
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 here">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
      </div>
    </div>
 </div><!-- row -->
 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-primary js-next-step2" href="#" role="button">Continue to Step 3</a>
    </div>
  </div><!-- row -->
  
</div>
</div>
<!-- end Step 2 -->


<!-- begin Step 3 -->
<div id="step3">

<div class="step-3 js-step-3">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 here">
      <h2 class="color-black">Step 3</h2>
      <hr>
    </div>
 </div><!-- row -->
 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 here">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div><!-- row -->
 
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-success" href="#" role="button">Submit</a>
    </div>
  </div><!-- row -->

</div>
</div>
<!-- end Step 3 -->
  
  </form>
</div>
```